# How do I brute force a password protected zip file with a three digit password?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

The problem is stated here:

> Sample Alien Zip file found at /tmp/alien-zip-2092.zip is password
> protected. We have worked out they are using a numerical three digit code. Brute
> force the Zip file to extract to /tmp
>
> Note: The script can timeout if this occurs, try narrowing down your
> search

My code is as follows:

```py
import zipfile
import itertools

digits = '0123456789'

for c in itertools.product(digits, repeat=3):
  password = ''.join(c)
  try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/alien-sample-42.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
      zip_ref.extractall(path='/tmp', pwd = bytes(password, 'utf-8'))
      break
  except:
    print('Password ' + password + ' failed')
```

When I submit this code it lists all three digit combinations but none of them extract the file.

Comment: You know that you could directly produce a number between 0 and 999 and format it with 0 padding? This would save you two loops ;)

Comment: Did you try alphabet combinations? Or alpha-numeric combinations?

Comment: Exception could be thrown for other reasons than wrong password.

Comment: I agree with the previous commentor.  Find out which exception is thrown for a bad password, and *only* "except" that error.  For the others, you want to know what happened.  In general "except" with no specific error is a very bad programing practice.

Comment: @mozway thank you but i'm not sure what you mean. how do you format with padding?

Comment: @FrankYellin i tried googling that but i can't find anything. i'm relatively new with python so i'm sorry if i'm a bit stupid.

Comment: @mozway I used intertools instead to limit my loops but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ruthvik when I add in letters it takes too long and times out:
`No response, your code is running longer than we expect for this challenge, can you tweak your code to fix this?`

Comment: How many passwords can you test before the script times out?

Comment: It's unclear what they mean by "try narrowing down your search". Either you brute-force by trying all combinations, or you don't.

Comment: @mozway this is a cyberstart challenge so it doesn't show what is happening while it is happening, it just gives you the end result.

Comment: @DuckHunt I meant do you know what how many attempts your script failed? Otherwise, can you write to disk? Have network access?

Comment: @mozway no, it is a restricted challenge. It does say that the code is a numerical three digit code though.

Comment: Have you tried random guesses? Or another starting point? The challenge might be designed to timeout before your reach the password when trying a "normal" order of the guesses (000, 001, 002...)

Comment: @mozway I have tried random guesses and it returns `Password 123 failed`
also, it doesn't time out when I only do numbers, and returns a list of all possible three digit combinations

Comment: Is this online somewhere so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: @KellyBundy It is through CyberStart, so you would have to pay for a liscense

Comment: thank you all, I had the wrong file (stupid me)

Comment: Sorry for what is coming, but...  ::facepalm::

Comment: lol @mozway I know and my only comfort is that no one else noticed either

Answer (score 4):

you had the wrong file... here is the correct code (for the people who still needs it)

```
import zipfile
import itertools

digits = '0123456789'

for c in itertools.product(digits, repeat=3):
  password = ''.join(c)
  try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/alien-zip-2092.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
      zip_ref.extractall(path='/tmp', pwd = bytes(password, 'utf-8'))
      break
  except:
    print('Password ' + password + ' failed')
    
pwd = bytes(password, 'utf-8')
```